# How to get the id of a Billing Plan for a certain Billing Agreement?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

PayPal REST API documentation says that the Billing Agreement object contains info about it's Billing Plan https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements#agreement (id, name, description, state etc.)

However, having the id of an agreement, I can't get the id of the plan associated with it.

I've used an [example for PayPal Node.js SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/subscription/billing_agreements/get.js) to get details of an agreement and got this response (truncated to improve readability):

```
{
   "id": "I-UR6MTL02G0UE",
   "state": "Active",
   "description": "Agreement for Basic (EUR) plan",
   "payer": {
     ...
   },
   "plan": {
     "payment_definitions": [
       {
         "type": "REGULAR",
         "frequency": "Month",
         "amount": {
           "currency": "EUR",
           "value": "7.99"
         },
         "cycles": "0",
         "charge_models": [
           {
             "type": "TAX",
             "amount": {
               "currency": "EUR",
               "value": "0.00"
             }
           },
           {
             "type": "SHIPPING",
             "amount": {
               "currency": "EUR",
               "value": "0.00"
             }
           }
         ],
         "frequency_interval": "1"
       }
     ],
     "merchant_preferences": {
       ...
     }
   },
   "start_date": "2017-06-19T07:00:00Z",
   "shipping_address": {
     ...
   },
   "agreement_details": {
     ...
   },
   "httpStatusCode": 200
}
```

As you can see in the `plan` section I've got info only about it's payment definitions, but I need to get it's id. So how can I achieve this?

Comment: I saw on rest api and it does return you the id. check this out https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/billing-plans-and-agreements/

Comment: Thanks. I've already checked this docs. For some reason it returns the id only when I create the agreement. But when I try to get the details of an agreement later, it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it's not currently possible because of an issue in PayPal REST API (see the issue on Github https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/issues/272).

Not sure how fast it will be fixed. Maybe they don't even plan to fix it as I've found similar issues on their Github created about three years ago.